# Customizing / extending / monkey patching Django Auth Backend

Tags: python, django, monkeypatching, extending

I am using [django-auth-ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/) to connect to an LDAP server for authentication. django-auth-ldap provides the setting `AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP`, which can be used to allow access only for users placed in a specific group. This works fine, but the option only allows to check one group; I want to check if a users is placed in either one or another group.

In the module `django_auth_ldap/backend.py` I could modify the method `_check_required_groups` of the class `LDAPUser(object)` to implement this behaviour. Modifying it directly works fine, but since changing the source would endup in a maintenance hell, I am searching for a solution to change this method without touching the source. Two ideas I had:

**1) Monkey Patching**

Change the `_check_required_groups` method of an instance of the `LDAPUser` class. The problem is that I have no idea where it is beeing instantiated. I am just using `LDAPSearch` and `GroupOfNamesType`  imported from `django_auth_ldap.config` in the settings file, and passing the string `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` into the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` tuple.

**2) Extending the module**

Create an own module, extending the original `django_auth_ldap` and using this instead of the original. I tried to create a new directory, adding an `__init__.py` with the line:

```
from django_auth_ldap import *
```

But using this module does not work, since it can't import `custom_auth.config`.

Any other suggestions or hints how to make one of those attempts to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be modular, DRY and true to the django philosophy in general, you need to create a class named `LDAPBackendEx` that would inherit from `LDAPBackend` and use this class to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` instead of `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend`. Also, you'dd create an `LDAPUserEx` that would inhert from `_LDAPUser` and override the `_check_required_groups` method.

So, the `LDAPUserEx` would be something like:

```
class LDAPUserEx(_LDAPUser):
    def _check_required_group(self):
        pass # Put your implementation here !
```

Now, concerning the implementation of `LDAPBackendEx`: Unfortuanately there is no way of defining a custom `_LDAPUser` class so you'd have to search every method that uses the `_LDAPUser` class and override it with `LDAPUserEx`. The correct methdod of implementing django-auth-ldap (and if we actually needed to be modular) would be to add an `user_class` attribute to LDAPBackend, initialize it to `_LDAPUser` and use that instead of `_LDAPUser`.

Checking the code  [here](https://github.com/christian-oudard/django-auth-ldap/blob/master/django_auth_ldap/backend.py), I found out that the methods of `LDAPBackend` that refer `_LDAPUser` are `authenticate`, `get_user` and `get_group_permissions`. So, the implementation of `LDAPBackendEx` would be something like this:

```
class LDAPBackendEx(LDAPBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        ldap_user = LDAPUserEx(self, username=username)
        user = ldap_user.authenticate(password)
        return user

   def get_user(self, user_id):
       pass # please put definition of get_user here changing _LDAPUser to LDAPUserEx

   def get_group_permissions(self, user):
       pass # please put definition of get_group_permissions here changing _LDAPUser to LDAPUserEx
```